# Round off each value of a given vector(B) to closest value in A

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given a set of numbers:

```
A = np.array([12,10,7,4,2,0,-3])
```

and another set of values:

```
B = np.array([14,8.8,2.3,-4,5.5])
```

Is there a method in python which can round off B to the nearest value of A?

Comment: for A and B as you have provided, can you tell us your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach:

```
res = A[np.abs(A-B[:, None]).argmin(axis=1)]

[12 10  2 -3  7]
```

To understand how this works from a pure Python perspective, consider this list comprehension:

```
[A[np.abs(A-b).argmin()] for b in B]
```

Note this does not deal with ties, `argmin` extracts the *first* minimum index.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an O(n log n) solution:

```
>>> AS = np.sort(A)
>>> bnd = (AS[:-1] + AS[1:]) / 2
>>> nearest = AS[bnd.searchsorted(B)]
>>> 
>>> nearest
array([12, 10,  2, -3,  4])
```

Or if you want ties to be rounded up:

```
>>> nearest = AS[bnd.searchsorted(B, 'right')]
>>> nearest
array([12, 10,  2, -3,  7])
```